# Compare and filter out data from separate SQL columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that looks similar to:

```
select userid, access, childaccess from table 1

union all

select userid, access, childaccess from table 2
```

Which returns a set of data that can look like:

```
JSMITH - Admin    - View1

JSMITH - Admin    - View2

JSMITH - Controls - NULL

JSMITH - View1    - NULL

JSMITH - View2    - NULL
```

I need to compare the data and remove any duplicates between Access and ChildAccess columns so that the data above looks like:

```
JSMITH - Admin    - View1

JSMITH - Admin    - View2

JSMITH - Controls - NULL
```

So we are removing results where the Access items equal the ChildAccess items.

Comment: First of all **MS SQL Server** or **MySQL** or both?

Comment: This would be a query for MS SQL Server

Comment: Use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`, it will remove duplication

Comment: What if you had an additional row `JSMITH - View1 - View3` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
WITH cte AS
( select userid, access, childaccess 
  from table_1
  union
  select userid, access, childaccess 
  from table_2
)
SELECT *
FROM cte c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM cte c2
                  WHERE c2.userid = c.userid
                    AND c2.childaccess = c.access);
```

Comment: This is perfect! THANK YOU!